# Possible to get RSSI of peripherals without connecting?

Tags: ios8, core-bluetooth

In the past, I was able to get rssi values off of peripherals by simply calling [peripheral rssi]. It seems now Apple has frustratingly deprecated this method and replaced it with [peripheral readRssi], which only allows it if you are connected to the peripheral. Does anyone know of any work around for this, as I want still want to be quickly scanning devices within vicinity and gain rssi readings at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CBCentralManagerDelegate` method 
`centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:` supplies the RSSI of the discovered peripheral in the 4th parameter.